# How do I compare two arrays to make sure that every object in the first array is present in the second in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, compare

I've written the following code with the intent of comparing two arrays and making sure that every element in array1 is present in array2. If an element is not present, it should return false. If it is present, it should return true.

```
array1.each do |x|
if (array2.include?(x))
    array2.delete_at(array2.index(x))   
    next
else return false
```

I have set it up to delete the element from the second array to account for duplicate objects, but I can't figure out where to return true.

I need it to iterate through the entire array and return true when it is confirmed that each element from the first array is present in the second array. Currently this code will return an array of the values that are present in both or false if an element that is not present in array2 is input.

Comment: Why do duplicates matter? Are you actually trying to check if the two arrays contain the same 'set' of elements? Allowing duplicity? ie, given [1, 1, 2] and [1, 2] should your code return true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if all elements of `array1` are included in `array2`:

```
array2 | array1 == array2
```

Edit: Removed incorrect code pointed out by Rustam A. Gasanov.

Comment: Could you explain what that operator means in this context and why this works?

Comment: The operators are union `|` and intersection `&` . Read more: http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/06/using-set-operators-with-ruby-arrays.html

Comment: Your solutions are not the same. If `array1 = [1, 2, 2]` and `array2 = [1, 2]` first will give `true`, second - `false`.

Comment: I think there's still a problem. If `array1 = [0]` and `array2 = [0,0]`, the answer should be `true`, yet `[0] | [0,0] => [0] != [0,0]`. Similarly, reversing the order should produce a false result but evaluates `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your method corrected to work:

```
def all_present_and_accounted_for?(array1,array2)
  array1.each do |x|
    if (array2.include?(x))
      array2.delete_at(array2.index(x))   
    else
      return false
    end
  end  
  true
end

array1 = [1,2,3,3,4]

array2 = [4,6,5,3,2,1,3,8]
all_present_and_accounted_for?(array1,array2) #=> true

array2 = [4,6,5,3,2,1,5,8]
all_present_and_accounted_for?(array1,array2) #=> false
```

You can improve that by making a copy of `array2` (so `array2` is not modified) and a couple of other small changes:

```
def all_present_and_accounted_for?(array1, array2)
  a2 = array2.dup
  array1.each do |n|
    return false unless i = a2.index(n)
    a2.delete_at(i)
  end
  true
end

array1 = [1,2,3,3,4]

all_present_and_accounted_for?(array1, [4,6,5,3,2,1,3,8])
  #=> true
all_present_and_accounted_for?(array1, [4,6,5,3,2,1,5,8])
  #=> false
```

Here's another way. First, a helper I've often wished for:

```
class Array
  def %(arr)
    arr.each_with_object(dup) do |e,a|
      i = a.index(e)  
      a.delete_at(i) if i
    end
  end
end
```

For example:

```
arr = [38, 38, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 60]
arr % [41, 60, 40, 38, 40, 41] 
  #=> [38, 40, 41, 41]
```

If a and b are two arrays, a%b is similar to a-b, except rather than removing all elements of a that are contained in b, it removes one character in a (the one with the smallest index) for each instance of that character in b. Now wouldn't this be a handy method to have as a built-in?

With this helper it's a simple matter to determine if every element in `array1` is contained in `array2`:

```
(array1 % array2).empty?
```

For example,

```
array1 = [1,2,3,3,4]
(array1 % [4,6,5,3,2,1,3,8]).empty? #=> true
(array1 % [4,6,5,3,2,1,5,8]).empty? #=> false
```